# Random Letter Choosing for Textbox

Tags: vb.net

So this code by Neethu Soman,

```
Dim input As String = TextBox2.Text '<--- this should be input "Hello I am Greg" 
    TextBox2.Text = "" '<--- clear the textbox to store output
    Dim rnd As New Random '<---- generating new random number 
    For Each c As Char In input '<--- iterate through each character
        If rnd.Next() Mod 2 = 0 Then
            TextBox2.Text &= UCase(c) '<--- if true then print particular letter in upperCase
        Else
            TextBox2.Text &= LCase(c) '<--- if true then print particular letter in LowerCase
        End If
    Next
```

basically does what is supposed to, it converts random letter to lower, and upper case with a 50/50 chance. Although, that one problem is that is clears the text, and rewrites it in its new converted form, which is the problem. Is there a way to make this work without having to clear the text?

Comment: You are going to have to either clear the text or just replace the previous text with the new text because strings are immutable in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for make a try with my answer, you can convert random letter to lower, Or upper case with a 50/50 chance using the following code without using `TextBox2.Text = ""`

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    Dim rnd As New Random'<--- Generating random number
    If rnd.Next() Mod 2 = 0 Then
        e.KeyChar = UCase(e.KeyChar) '<--- if true then change key char to upperCase
    Else
        e.KeyChar &= LCase(e.KeyChar) '<--- if true then change key char to LowerCase
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to do it in button click means:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim randomString As String = ""
    Dim rnd As New Random
    For Each c As Char In TextBox2.Text
        If rnd.Next() Mod 2 = 0 Then
            randomString &= UCase(c)
        Else
            randomString &= LCase(c)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = randomString
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I make this execute with a button?

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly